# Make images start to appear on canvas when clicked

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, onclick

Basically I have got my code to work as in that when the page loads the images start showing up one after the other on the canvas, but instead I'd like the images to start showing on mouse click, can you show me how to do this?

```
<script>

window.onload = function() {



var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas").addEventListener("mousedown",    function() // Selects the canvas element
var context=canvas.getContext("2d"); 

var img1 =new Image() //creates a variable for a new image
var img2 =new Image() //creates a variable for a new image
var img3 =new Image() //creates a variable for a new image
var img4 =new Image() //creates a variable for a new image

img1.src = "canvasimg1.png" // Gets image
img2.src = "canvasimg2.png" // Gets image
img3.src = "canvasimg3.png" // Gets image
img4.src = "canvasimg4.png" // Gets image

setTimeout(                                             // Settimeout - execute the passed function after the amount of milliseconds
    function() { context.drawImage(img1,23,20); }       // Function to be executed
, 1000);                                                // Amount of milliseconds to delay for

setTimeout(                                             // Settimeout - execute the passed function after the amount of milliseconds
    function() { context.drawImage(img2, 23, 60); }     // Function to be executed
, 6000);                                                // Amount of milliseconds to delay for

setTimeout(                                             // Settimeout - execute the passed function after the amount of milliseconds
    function() { context.drawImage(img3, 25, 120); }    // Function to be executed
, 11000);                                               // Amount of milliseconds to delay for

setTimeout(                                             // Settimeout - execute the passed function after the amount of milliseconds
    function() { context.drawImage(img4, 150, 180); }   // Function to be executed
, 16000);                                               // Amount of milliseconds to delay for
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the images to start showing up when the canvas is clicked on, you put the four setTimeout functions in another function and you call this function only when there is a click on the canvas!

```
 <canvas id="exemple" width="200" height="200" onclick="showImage()">


function showImage(){
    setTimout.....
     ....
   }
```